# JS / Ruby AES 256 symmetry

Tags: javascript, ruby, encryption, aes

I'm encrypting with Ruby and decrypting with JavaScript using AES-256 but I'm having trouble crossing platforms, i.e. the JS returns gibberish when decrypting the output from Ruby.

I'm using the JS AES implementation from here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html

```
var decrypted = Aes.Ctr.decrypt(encrypted, key, 256);
```

and OpenSSL / Ruby:

```
def encrypt(string, key)
  Base64.encode64(aes(key, string)).gsub /\s/, ''
end

def aes(key,string)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")
  cipher.encrypt
  cipher.key = Digest::SHA256.digest(key)
  cipher_text = cipher.update(string)
  cipher_text << cipher.final
  return cipher_text
end
```

In ruby I get:

```
encrypt("This is a test", "password")
# => "zDMm47GniTQ2p5a5UqSDbg=="
```

But when decrypting in JS, I get:

```
Aes.Ctr.decrypt("zDMm47GniTQ2p5a5UqSDbg==", "password", 256);
# => "Ü}$> 3"
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've had better luck in the past using http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end I used Gibberish AES which has both a Ruby and JavaScript implementation written by the same author:

https://github.com/mdp/gibberish-aes

https://github.com/mdp/gibberish

Answer (score 1):

Does the JS library expect the ciphertext to be Base64 encoded? Basically what you are doing is;

```
              key
               |
               v
plaintext -> encipher -> ciphertext -> Base64 encode -> "zDMm47GniTQ2p5a5UqSDbg=="
```

but then you try and reverse it like this;

```
                               key
                                |
                                v
"zDMm47GniTQ2p5a5UqSDbg==" -> decipher -> plaintext
```

You are missing the Base64 decode of "zDMm47GniTQ2p5a5UqSDbg==" before doing the decipher. In fact when I tried to reproduce this (using a java AES implementation) I got an error because "zDMm47GniTQ2p5a5UqSDbg==" isn't even a multiple of 16 bytes in length, which is a necessary for this type on cipher (AES block size is 128 bits).

**Update**
I'm not sure I'd trust that JS AES implementation, its definitely doing something funny. It says it operates in CTR mode for a start, which is probably not what you want (you probably want CBC).

Comment: The JS implementation handles the Base64 decode internally but I hadn't realised CTR / CBC is a problem. I'll try something else. Thanks for the reply!